# How to enter into process running on gdb?

Tags: linux, terminal, gdb

So I was trying to debug a program that runs on two node. I use yod as task launcher.

```
 yod -hosts node01,node02 ./dist_task -nl 2
```

The program is stuck. So I wanted to use the gdb like this

```
 yod -hosts node01,node02 gdb ./dist_task
```

I am into gdb session in node01 but for node02 I am not able to. What happens is, I can see the the process running (gdb ./dist_task) on remote node (node02 by htop) but I am not able to step into it. I tried doing attach (I am just trying to attach to gdb process) like how normally we would to a process but in my case since it already is gdb I get information about the gdb but not about the process.

ps :I tried doing through xterm but no luck there either (I am not able to pop two xterm)

Comment: Have you tied to attach `strace` to the process? Btw `waiting` doesn't mean `stuck`

Comment: but this way I could only b able to see the system call .. I actually wanted to do gdb :p .. yeah U are right about waiting/stuck think I will correct it.

Comment: Another option could be `ltrace`, check if your system supports it.

Comment: hmm I do have ltrace .. I might try this then

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `attach`

From the docs:

```
attach process-id
    This command attaches to a running process—one that was started outside gdb
```

You can try launching them as  `yod -hosts node01,node02 ./dist_task -nl 2` then attaching to them via the `attach` command from the gdb prompt or using `gdb -a <pid>`

Comment: I did that and it does not work .. since by the time I go and do attach program has already run ... I wanted to do gdb from the start of the program

Comment: You may want to look into gdbserver then. Alternatively, send a SIGINT to the process immediately after starting it so it doesn't continue executing and GDB has something to attach to.